# C# Client Server Data transfer - Raspberry Pi

Tags: c#, .net, raspberry-pi

I am developing software for Raspberry PI, where I am planning to run a C# application using .Net core deployed as stand-alone executable including .Net virtual machine.

My Requirements:
I need to communicate with clients to download large content and send it to other clients in a secure way

What solution best suits in this case:

1) Client-Server MVC application
2) Achieve this By creating a REST API
3) Use Sockets

Please suggest!